# Android | PHP | MySql - Save emoji to Mysql server from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, emoji

How can I send text with **emoji** from Android app to server and save it correctly in MySql database?

In Android app I've pass some parametres with post method to php server, then I save it in to MySql database. But I've 2 problems with emoji

- In php I get this emoji  converted in "="
- If I try to save it manually in MySql I get "????" and the following error `Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8D' for column 'name' at row 1`. The table and the field have **utf8mb4_bin collation**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use StringEscapeUtils Apache Library
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

For saving the unicodes in database you have to encode them. So send your unicodes to server by encoding like

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(/* string message*/)
```

For displaying the encoded unicode in android

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(/* string message*/)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. I've added also `addslashes(string)` in PHP.